# mushrooms in raised garden beds around strawberries

Tags: identification, fungus

Orange mushrooms growing around strawberry in raised garden bed. What are they, and what are they a sign of?

I’m in Vancouver BC, and it’s late July (summer). Plant hardiness zone 8b.

[image: garden bed mushroom]

[image: underside]

[image: cap]

Answer (score 11):

It's one of the bonnet mushrooms, not sure which - maybe Mycena acicula, the orange bonnet, but they will do no harm to your strawberries. These are just the fruiting bodies of mycelium present in the soil, which will be feeding off organic debris in the soil mix. You can just twist them off at the base and dispose of them if you like - cover your hand with a plastic bag to enclose the mushroom before doing so to prevent spore spread, but they will disappear on their own within a week or two.